# TCP Socket Server - A method for detecting incoming data

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am trying to write a server that will listen on a port, accept an incoming client connection and then put that client connection in a stack to wait for a future message to arrive. Ideally when a message arrives, I'd like to fire an event that then allows the server to perform an action.

I've written almost all of that...I am using `AcceptTCPClient()` to actually pick up a new client connection which is fine. I then create a thread, pass the socket to a class that holds the client state and some other data. However the only way I can think to block and wait for a future incoming connection on that thread is to call something like NetworkStream.Read() which then blocks until bytes arrive.

So here is the fundamental problem - I am using Protobuff-net which allows me to deserialise a network stream rather than an individual byte array.  So by reading the first couple of bytes, I've got to reset the read, pass the networkstream to the protobuff deserialize method and then continue.

All I really want is a method that blocks until some bytes are detected but doesn't require me to actually **read** the bytes until I'm ready.

Anyone have any ideas how I could achieve this?

**Update**

As the comments below suggested, this is not something that seems to be supported by .Net  therefore the simplest solution seems to be to use **Tsukasa** example below which uses async read/write.

I've written it to consume all the bytes on the wire and then pass those bytes to the protobuff Deserialize method.

Not what I wanted but it works fine. Thanks all for the assitance.

```
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    private Socket socket;
    private NetworkStream networkStream;
    private AsyncCallback callbackRead;
    private AsyncCallback callbackWrite;

    public Socket Socket
    {
        get { return socket; }            
    }

    public ClientProxy(Socket clientSocket)
    {
        socket = clientSocket;
        networkStream = new NetworkStream(clientSocket);
        callbackRead = new AsyncCallback(OnReadComplete);
        callbackWrite = new AsyncCallback(OnWriteComplete);
    }

    public void ReadAsync()
    {
        networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, callbackRead, null);
    }

    private void OnReadComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int bytesRead = networkStream.EndRead(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {                
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            Message data;
            data = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Message>(stream, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);

            if (data.Type == Chat.Type.User && data.Action == Chat.Action.Add)
            {
                Communication.RegisterClient(data.From, socket.Handle.ToString());
            }                
            Communication.readMessage(data);

            ReadAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            networkStream.Close();
            socket.Close();
            networkStream = null;
            socket = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to use TcpListener class.

Comment: @user1929959... and that would help how, exactly?

Comment: You should use a buffered memory stream and read from the network stream through it.

Comment: @user1929959, that doesn't solve his problem

Comment: Can you be more concrete? Is there anything wrong with just having protobuf-net block on the stream? If you are concerned about thread count I'm sure protobuf-net supports async IO.

Comment: Are you using `BeginReceive` and a callback or the synchronous equivalent? We're really just guessing if you don't provide any of your code.

Comment: Your new code assumes that you receive all data in a single read. This is not so. Your code will break sooner or later. You'll silently lose data. If you describe the actual problem that you have, instead of some contrived requirement to not block, we can help you better.

Comment: True.  I simplifed the snippet for posting here.  I've implimented while DataAvailiable loop to ensure I have all the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeginRead() which would allow you to have an event called when data is ready, that way your process can be in a blocked state where the OS will only awake it when the resource is ready

```
class Client
{
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    private Socket socket;
    private NetworkStream networkStream;
    private AsyncCallback callbackRead;
    private AsyncCallback callbackWrite;

    public Client(Socket clientSocket)
    {
        socket = clientSocket;
        networkStream = new NetworkStream(clientSocket);
        callbackRead = new AsyncCallback(OnReadComplete);
        callbackWrite = new AsyncCallback(OnWriteComplete);
    }

    public void StartRead()
    {
        networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, callbackRead, null);
    }

    private void OnReadComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int bytesRead = networkStream.EndRead(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            string s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            //do something with complete data here
            networkStream.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, bytesRead, callbackWrite, null);
        }
        else
        {
            networkStream.Close();
            socket.Close();
            networkStream = null;
            socket = null;
        }
    }

    private void OnWriteComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        networkStream.EndWrite(ar);
        networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, callbackRead, null);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
bool running = true;
IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(localAddr, 3000);
tcpListener.Start();

while (running)
{
    while (!tcpListener.Pending())
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    Socket socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
    Client client = new Client(socket);
    client.StartRead();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He wants to know how to have the "HandleClientComms" thread block until data is received *without actually performing a read*

Comment: Added HandleClientComms

Comment: Its a little hidden: "However the only way I can think to block and wait for a future incoming connection on that thread is to call something like NetworkStream.Read() which then blocks until bytes arrive." And the problem with this is the next paragraph of the question.

Comment: I guess i'm a little confused by what he is asking. while(myNetworkStream.DataAvailable) and then wait until something is triggered to then work with the data?

Comment: @Tsukasa at the moment I don't think the question can be answered. I'm waiting for clarification.

Comment: @Tsukasa I think he wants the inverse while(!DataAvailable); then read. Of course you don't want a spin lock, so he wants a call that emulates the while loop but simply blocks the thread.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET BeginRead() which would allow you to have an event called when data is ready, that way your process can be in a blocked state where the OS will only awake it when the resource is ready?

Comment: @Tsukasa Sounds reasonable (I've always used Read so I can't speak to it). If you revise your answer to include it (a link to documentation would be great!) I would happily upvote the answer.

Comment: I don't know if this is getting to what you are looking for or not. Hopefully I'm somewhere in the ballpark lol.

Answer (score 2):

You can poll the `DataAvailable` property but it's unreliable and inefficient.

A better way is to prefix the protobuf stream with a length prefix. It also allows to do a read without reading the protobuf message. By using a prefix you can invoke a asynchronous read which will return as soon as there is something available (just configure the Read to read only 4 bytes if you are using a  length header).

If you don't want to take care of the network operations yourself you can use my apache licensed library. Here is a sample using protobuf-net: http://blog.gauffin.org/2014/06/easy-and-perfomant-clientserver-communication-with-protobuf-net-griffin-framework/

Comment: @usr: afaik there is no solution to the exact problem? So what's wrong with giving alternative solutions?

Comment: We don't know what his problem is. The question is unanswerable as it stands. Any answer for an unanswerable question is wrong. Do *you* know what his problem is? He wants to block, but not inside protobuf-net. No idea why.

Comment: He defines it like this: `All I really want is a method that blocks until some bytes are detected but doesn't require me to actually read the bytes until I'm ready`.

Comment: a) you have not provided a realistic solution to that and b) this is probably a misguided requirement. You cannot provide alternatives if you do not understand what he wants to achieve.

Comment: that's why I said "afaik there is no solution to the exact problem? So what's wrong with giving alternative solutions? " to your first comment.

Comment: Sorry I'm unclear as to why the requirement is either misguided or doesn't make sense?  I think its perfectly logical. I want to detect or have an event on an incoming data stream without actually reading the byte stream? I guess this makes sense to me but not others.  Which bit is unclear and I'll try and rephrase?

Comment: There is no way of doing that.